# White Space between inline block elements

Tags: whitespace, css

What is the actual value of the space between inline block elements relative to the container's font-size? It seems to be about 0.3ems.

Does anyone know if this is correct?

**Revising my origin question to be more specific.**

Is there a standard cross browser width of the U+0020 character relative to the font size if so what is it?

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML/CSS. `inline-block` elements respect white space in the coding..

Comment: Please also provide the browsers used for your analyses AND the doctype of your document.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Perhaps this varies w/ browsers I'll look at that as well.

Comment: Please, insert any relevant COMMENT in your initial question. In the meanwhile, see if this answers your question : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop  Thinking about it, it might be 1 monospace character width, isn't it ?

Comment: Although I tend to use the `font-size:o` fix on the parent, I have found the space to be approx. 0.25em. A negative left margin of that amount usually does the trick.

Comment: @Paulie_D That seems to be correct thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White space between inline block elements (or inline elements) has the same effect as a single SPACE U+0020 character, by HTML specifications. (Ref.: Section [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html) in HTML 4.01 spec.) Text justification could affect this, however, but presumably it is not relevant here.

The width of SPACE depends on the font, i.e. it is set by the font designer. According to Microsoft’s [Character design standards](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/developers/fdsspec/spaces.aspx) for Space Characters, the minimum width of SPACE should be 1/5 em; an “average” value is 1/4 em; and for a “wide” font, 1/3 em; the maximum would be 1/2 em.